# Saves questions feature: cannot move question in created list

Tags: bug, status-completed, saves

I saved the following question:
[Fastest method to escape HTML tags as HTML entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499078/fastest-method-to-escape-html-tags-as-html-entities)
in the "For later" list.

Then I created a new list "Code for standard library".
Previously, I had created a list "Support" for another question.
I tried to move the question above from "For later" to "Code for standard library".
But only "For later list" and "Support" list were available.
[image: Both questions in support list]

[image: Missing list]

Comment: Also reported [here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384057/348196).

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the "almost duplicate". Before creating my bug report, I checked the questions but I did not thought of checking answers on the main related "question". I upvoted the related answer.

Comment: Thanks for reporting. This has been ticketed in our backlog. I was able to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix has been deployed. Please let me know if you're still experiencing issues. This was a regression caused by another bug that we deployed recently.